# prior range of uniform(0,50) vs uniform(0,500)

Tags: r, bayesian, rstan

I’ve just started with Bayesian analysis and rstan. I run the following really simple example (borrowed by the book Statistical Rethinking by Richard McElreath - there he's using his function but I want to code it directly in rstan)

For sigma I want to use a non informative  prior (as suggested by the book)  `sigma ~ uniform(0,50)`
However, the simulation faces problems and returns a sigma (mean) close to 50.  If I use a `uniform(0,70)` then the sigma is close to 70.
But by using a much wider prior `sigma ~ uniform(0,500)` everything works fine. 
My question is, since data’s variance is around 5 why a prior `uniform(0,50)` does not work?
Thanks

```
library(rstan)
library(rethinking)
library(dplyr)

data(Howell1)
dat1 <- Howell1
d2 <- dat1[ dat1$age >= 18 , ]

plot( d2$height ~ d2$weight )
lm(d2$height ~ d2$weight) %>% summary


model.stan2 <- '
data{
 int <lower=1> N;
 real weight_bar;
 vector[N] height;
 vector[N] weight;
}

parameters{
 real alpha;
 real beta;
 real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model{
 vector[N] mu;

// Priors
 alpha ~ normal(178, 20); 
 beta ~ lognormal(0,1); 
 sigma ~ uniform(0,50);  

 mu = alpha + beta*(weight - weight_bar); 

// Likelihood
 height ~ normal( mu, sigma);
}
'

stan_samples2 <- stan(model_code = model.stan2, 
    data = list(
        N= nrow(d2),
        height=d2$height, 
        weight=d2$weight,
        weight_bar= mean(d2$weight)
        )
    )

precis(stan_samples2)
```

Comment: You need to declare sigma with an upper bound constraint if you want to give it a uniform prior.  Beta needs a lower bound of zero given its prior.  We don't recommend uniform priors as they are not uninformative the way they would be with maximum likelihood.  Instead, if the data is consistent with values beyond the boundary, mass will pile up at the boundary and affect the posterior mean.  We strongly recommend soft constraints that are at least weakly informative in defining the scale of the answer.